# Why maven is always pointing to lower version of JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jenkins

I have maven project where my driver script is testng test and when i ran the test with testng suite it works perfect.

But when i ran the test with pom.xml or jenkins it is always complaining saying it is pointing to lower version though i configured the JRE and Compiler to latest version in Eclipse.

How to overcome this issue:

Following is jenkins logs:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace C:\Users\Uday\.jenkins\workspace\MavenProj
FSSCM.checkout D:\FrameworkDemos\MavenHAF to C:\Users\Uday\.jenkins\workspace\MavenProj
FSSCM.check completed in 62 milliseconds
Parsing POMs
Discovered a new module MavenWebHAF:MavenWebHAF MavenWebHAF
Modules changed, recalculating dependency graph
[MavenProj] $ "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java" -cp C:\Users\Uday\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-agent-1.5.jar;E:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.3.3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;E:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.3.3/conf/logging jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven31Main E:\Softwares\apache-maven-3.3.3 C:\Users\Uday\.jenkins\war\WEB-INF\lib\remoting-2.52.jar C:\Users\Uday\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven31-interceptor-1.5.jar C:\Users\Uday\.jenkins\plugins\maven-plugin\WEB-INF\lib\maven3-interceptor-commons-1.5.jar 52877
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started

Executing Maven:  -B -f C:\Users\Uday\.jenkins\workspace\MavenProj\pom.xml test -Dtest=TestSuite.TestAutomationDriver

[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for MavenWebHAF:MavenWebHAF:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.relevantcodes:extentreports:jar should use a variable instead of a hard-coded path E:\Programming Samples\Selenium Jars\extentreports_Updated.jar @ line 33, column 21
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for org.monte:media:jar should use a variable instead of a hard-coded path E:\Programming Samples\Selenium Jars\MonteScreenRecorder.jar @ line 40, column 21
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.sun:tools:jar should use a variable instead of a hard-coded path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\lib\tools.jar @ line 52, column 29
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building MavenWebHAF 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ MavenWebHAF ---

[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Uday\.jenkins\workspace\MavenProj\src\main\resources

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ MavenWebHAF ---

[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ MavenWebHAF ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Uday\.jenkins\workspace\MavenProj\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ MavenWebHAF ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 7 source files to C:\Users\Uday\.jenkins\workspace\MavenProj\target\test-classes

[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Uday/.jenkins/workspace/MavenProj/src/test/java/FrameworkLibraries/FunctionLibraries/CommonFunctionLibrary.java:[244,39] strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Uday/.jenkins/workspace/MavenProj/src/test/java/FrameworkLibraries/FunctionLibraries/CommonFunctionLibrary.java:[287,39] strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
[INFO] 2 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.643 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-09-29T23:47:29+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 24M/273M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Users\Uday\.jenkins\workspace\MavenProj\pom.xml to MavenWebHAF/MavenWebHAF/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/MavenWebHAF-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project MavenWebHAF: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Uday/.jenkins/workspace/MavenProj/src/test/java/FrameworkLibraries/FunctionLibraries/CommonFunctionLibrary.java:[244,39] strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
[ERROR] /C:/Users/Uday/.jenkins/workspace/MavenProj/src/test/java/FrameworkLibraries/FunctionLibraries/CommonFunctionLibrary.java:[287,39] strings in switch are not supported in -source 1.5
[ERROR] (use -source 7 or higher to enable strings in switch)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
channel stopped

Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maven always uses default Java installation. Judging by the errors you posted the Java version on your system is something other than Java 7 ( < Java v7). I don't know if you have multiple Java versions installed  but you might resolve this problem in one of the two ways:

- upgrade Java version
- tell Maven which Java version you need to use explicitly by specifying Maven compiler plugin with desired Java version. Take a look into Maven plugin management - https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Plugin_Management

Here is the sample of such configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.7</source>
        <target>1.7</target>
        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Open your `pom` and see whether you have configured an older `Java` version for source version in `maven compiler plugin` configuration.

If so, setting it to a newer version will fix the problem. For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```